# Is it possible to have predefined heights for Gridster columns?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, gridster

I'm using gridster plugin to display some widget content in a web page. Widget content re-size option is allowed for users.

When a user re-size a widget, I want to restrict widget height to go as 2,4,8,12..etc. Not like 1,2,3,4,5. So that user cannot re-size into different size but only for pre-defined sizes.

Any idea how to achieve this?